# pcre2.h: No such file or directory

Tags: php, homebrew, openswoole

I try to install `openswoole` on my mac machine. I have this issue when installing it.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.29/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:25:10: fatal error: pcre2.h: No such file or directory
 #include "pcre2.h"
```

I used the command `brew install pcre` to fix this issue as others recommend, but I always get the same result. I try to open the folder `pcre` I only see one `php_pcre.h` file inside it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/include/pcre.h /usr/include/       "replace your file location here"
sudo pecl install apc
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. I get it now. I just change the location of the folder to link the pcr2.h. I have this location folder `/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.29/include/php/ext/pcre`

Comment: for future help this resolved my problem https://freek.dev/2151-fixing-the-dreaded-pcre2h-file-not-found-error-when-installing-imagick which is similar

Answer (score 61):

Here's simplest solution. I have finally solved my problem. I used PHP 8.1.7 - Mac Pro 2022 - Apple Silicon (M1)

My errors: fatal error: 'pcre2.h' file not found

The solution that I used:

1. `brew install pcre2`
2. `ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/pcre2/include/pcre2.h /opt/homebrew/opt/php@8.1/include/php/ext/pcre/`

   Beware of the PHP version in the destination, adjust as-needed.
   Then, re-run the installation that failed, e.g. apcu or openswoole.
3. `pecl install ...`

Success Installation:

[image]

Hope it help you :) Thanks

Comment: Hello @Alex, all the device features you mentioned are the same. I found the source of the error. Thank you!

Comment: It works also with PHP 8.2.0

Comment: It works for me using php 7.4

Comment: Also OK with PHP 8.3.

Answer (score 3):

For M1 MacBooks, this is how I fixed that error when installing rdkafka.

```
pecl install rdkafka
```

Error

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/include/php/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:23:10: fatal error: 'pcre2.h' file not found
#include "pcre2.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~
```

Solution

```
ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre2/10.40/include/pcre2.h /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/include/php/ext/pcre/pcre2.h
```

See the new link

```
➜ cd /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/include/php/ext/pcre
➜ ls -l
total 8
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ddhondup  admin    48 Oct  6 15:29 pcre2.h -> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre2/10.40/include/pcre2.h
-rw-rw-r--  1 ddhondup  admin  3970 Oct  1  2021 php_pcre.h
```

After adding the link, it worked.

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/rdkafka.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/rdkafka-6.0.3
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=rdkafka.so" to php.ini
```

Comment: If brew install librdkafka did not work, try https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1025#issuecomment-827675182

Answer (score 2):

for me the path was different, I needed to find it by

```
brew --cellar
```

and then exact command above

```
 ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/pcre2/10.42/include/pcre2.h /opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@8.1/8.1.20/include/php/ext/pcre/pcre2.h
```

so you need to check pre version, php version and change the paths accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install from source on a mac you can also do:

```
git clone git@github.com:PCRE2Project/pcre2.git
brew install autoconf automake libtool
cd pcre2
./autogen.sh
```

This will generate the configure file inside the pcre2 directory. Then [run](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/pcre2.html):

```
CFLAGS='-O2 -Wall' ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/                       \
            --docdir=/usr/local/share/doc/pcre2-10.42 \
            --enable-unicode                    \
            --enable-jit                        \
            --enable-pcre2-16                   \
            --enable-pcre2-32                   \
            --enable-pcre2grep-libz             \
            --enable-pcre2grep-libbz2           \
            --enable-pcre2test-libreadline      \
            --disable-static                    &&
make
```

check that it passes the tests:

```
make check
```

and finally install with:

```
sudo make install
```